# QAudioDecoder "GStreamer; Unable to start decoding process"

Tags: c++, qt, gstreamer

I get the following Error

```
GStreamer; Unable to start decoding process
```

in the Console when i try to start the `QAudioDecoder`.

The following code:

```
void Media::decode(Memo* memo){
   decoder = new QAudioDecoder();
   format.setSampleRate(48000);
   format.setChannelCount(1);
   format.setSampleSize(8);
   format.setCodec("audio/pcm");
   format.setSampleType(QAudioFormat::UnSignedInt); 
   format.setByteOrder(QAudioFormat::LittleEndian);
   decoder->setAudioFormat(format);
   decoder->setSourceFilename(memo->getPathMedia());
   connect(decoder, SIGNAL(bufferReady()), this, SLOT(readBuffer()));
   decoder->start();
}



void Media::readBuffer(){
    buffer = decoder->read();
}
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: check gstreamer debug logs

Comment: you can check gstreamer debug logs with running your app with GST_DEBUG=3 for example - you can set this also in QtCreator at Project > Run > Build Environment (then just fill value with 3)

Comment: @otopolsky In my Project i only can build this Project. In the Build Environment i didn't finde GST_DEBUG therefore i added this with the value 3. But in the console appeared no debug.

Comment: you just add *new* env variable in Project > Run > Build Environment as I wrote.. and set its value to 3 for example.. I hope there is really used gstreamer in that... you can also run your binary/exe file with preceeded: `GST_DEBUG=3 ./yourapp`

Answer (score 0):

As @nayana suggested, I enabled GStreamer debug log with `GST_DEBUG=3` and it showed that the source file name was uncorrectly set :

`filesrc gstfilesrc.c:632:gst_file_src_uri_set_uri:<source> Invalid URI 'file:file:///home/rom1/Music/track01.mp3'`

Just remove the `file:` prefix and it works.

```
// In my source file ...
QString source = qvariant_cast<QString>(audioPlayer->property("source"));

source.remove(0, 7);

qDebug() << "Loading media" << source;
decoder.setSourceFilename(source);
decoder.start();
```